# Error when trying to create log axes in R (xyplot) "Math.factor(x,xbase) : 'log' not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics, lattice

TL;DR: I'm getting the above (and below) error. How do I fix it?

Since I'm *relatively* new to R, this has me stumped. I'm trying to create an `xyplot` where both the axes are log-transformed. I've gotten this far:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(`APC-H7-A`~`PE-Cy5-A`,lymphocytes, smooth=FALSE, 
       xlim=c(-100,10000), ylim=c(-100,10000),
       scales=list(x=list(log=10),y=list(log=10)))
```

And I keep getting an error:

> Error in Math.factor(x, xbase) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors

I'm guessing that the error means something in my code isn't recognised as a number? but I don't really know where to start looking.

Lymphocytes is an object of `flowFrame` class, within the `flowCore` package:

**Description.** This class represents the data contained in a FCS file or similar data structure. There are three parts of the data:*

- A numeric matrix of the raw measurement values with *rows=events* and *columns=parameters*
- Annotation for the parameters (e.g. the measurement channels, stains, dynamic range)
- Additional annotation provided through keywords in the FCS file*

Comment: Are APC-H7-A and/or PE-Cy5-A by any chance... factors? Please provide enough details for us to either reproduce (`dput()`) or give an educated guess (`str()`) of what's going on.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525292

Comment: are the 2 selected columns numeric? what if you try `as.numeric`? `xyplot(as.numeric(lymphocytes$'APC-H7-A') ~ as.numeric(lymphocytes$'PE-Cy5-A'), smooth = FALSE, ...)`

Comment: No the columns aren't numeric (but they aren't vectors either). deeenes answer, and my reply, give a bit more detail. Though `as.numeric` will probably be really useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex data structure and it is not straightforward to access the raw data. The manual page of `flowFrame` (see `help(flowFrame)`) says that we can index this object, and with the `exprs` method is the way to the raw data. Also this class has its own plotting methods, I assume you have a good reason why you choose `lattice` instead. With loading the example data the way below I could run your plotting code:

```
require(flowCore)
require(lattice)
data(GvHD)

xyplot(exprs(GvHD[[1]][, "FL4-H"]) ~ exprs(GvHD[[1]][, "FL2-H"]),
        smooth=FALSE,
        xlim=c(-100,10000),
        ylim=c(-100,10000),
        scales=list(x=list(log=10),
                    y=list(log=10)),
        xlab = "FL2-H",
        ylab = "FL4-H")
```

I don't know what is `FL2-H`, `FL4-H` and index `1` in this data array, but I am sure you will find out quickly as you know your data.

Comment: Oh! I see now. I've been using a package called flowViz for my plotting, and I had been using their implementation of lattice xyplot as opposed to actual lattice. I'd just been assuming they were the same thing because the function name was the same -.- stupid mistake. Question though: why does the format of the data (numerical, vector, etc) matter if the logarithm is only to be applied to the scale? Shouldn't this be independent of the data?

Comment: that is definitely not independent from the data, as the value of each data point along that scale need to be logarithm transformed in order to get the coordinate of that point on the plot. just try for example `log(as.factor(c(1,2,3)))`, and you will get the same error as in your question

Comment: note: if you have methods with identical names from different packages, the one loaded later masks the other. usually you get a message about this at loading the package. you can be sure that you access the method from the package you want by using double colons: `lattice::xyplot(...)`

Comment: Thanks. I realised that my data is already transformed, and that the reason my plots looked skewed is that there were outliers skewing the way my data was handled at another stage -.- I just assumed that I had to transform the axes because the tick marks were labelled in linear.